# n-bit addition over $GF(2^n)$ vs. addition modulo $2^n$

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, number-theory

I am currently studying the cryptanalysis of Speck, but I am feeling confused about the addition in Speck. I am not sure whether the addition in Speck is done through n-bit addition over $GF(2^n)$ or addition modulo $2^n$. I have learned that the elements of $GF(2^n)$ for any $n$ can be represented as $n$-bit bitstrings, and their addition is done through bitwise XOR. I've found that in *Improved Differential Cryptanalysis of Round-Reduced Speck* the addition in Speck may be addition over $GF(2^n)$. However, I am not sure why addition over $GF(2^n)$ and XOR are used to achieve nonlinearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additions are done modulo $2^n$.  The additions are the only source of nonlinearity; if they were done in $GF(2^n)$ (which, as you correctly point out, is equivalent to xor), there would be no nonlinearity, and so the cipher would be trivially weak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!